# Selecting data between dates in SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012 and I want to create a query that I can use in a gridview.

Basically the data is a list of statuses (restricted, unavailable and available) and each has a datetime next to them.

I want to display in my gridview the dates and statuses when a certain status was held.

So for example

[image]

The other issue I have is the top line of the grid ie if the status was changed today I need to show that.

My SQL skills aren't up to this so any help offered would be great.

Comment: dateTo are input by user or pass by you or you want to calculate it for current date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MSSQL 2012 you can use [LEAD()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx) function

```
select Status,
       StartDate,
       LEAD(StartDate, 1,null) 
         OVER (ORDER BY startDate) 
        as EndDate
FROM T
ORDER BY StartDate
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/46e19/3)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  Status_Current.yourDate   AS Date_From,
  Status_Next.yourDate      AS Date_To,
  Status_Current.yourStatus AS Status
FROM
  yourData   AS Status_Current
LEFT JOIN
  yourData   AS Status_Next
    ON Status_next.yourData = (SELECT TOP 1 lookup.yourDate
                                 FROM yourData   AS lookup
                                WHERE lookup.yourDate > Status_Current.yourDate
                             ORDER BY lookup.yourDate ASC
                              )
ORDER BY
  Status_Current.yourDate DESC
```